# Find the volume of the largest parallelpiped with faces parallel to coordinate planes $x= 0$,$y = 0$,$z=0$

Tags: geometry, optimization

Question :  Find the volume of the largest parallelpiped with faces parallel to coordinate planes $x= 0$,$y = 0$,$z=0$ that can be inscribed in one octant of ellipsoid.

I tried making some initial equations but don't know where to start. This is an Optimization problem of the case stated above

Comment: Were you given the equation of the ellipsoid, or enough information to find the equation? You will end up with an optimization problem that can be solved using calculus, or the arithmetic mean geometric mean inequality.

Comment: No, this is the only statement of the question

Comment: Then the problem is strange. Maybe they expect you to use the general ellipsoid in "standard" position, equation $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$. Let the corner of the box on the ellipsoid be $(x,y,z)$. Then the volume is $xyz$, which we want to maximize subject to $(x,y,z)$ satisfying the equation. Now you can use standard tools.